# Dart isolate call or send

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I have a couple questions about how isolate works :

1) What is the difference between `call` and `send` and when I should use `call` over `send`?

2) Just curiosity, is there any way to chain isolate like we chain `Future` ?

3)

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
echo() {
  port.receive((msg, reply) {
    print('I received: $msg');
  });
}

main() {
  var sendPort = spawnFunction(echo);
  sendPort.call('Hello from main');
}
```

It displays : I received: Hello from main

but when I use `send`, it prints nothing, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`call()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate/SendPort.html#call) method on [`SendPort`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate/SendPort.html) as a simple way to send a message and receive a reply. The [`call()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate/SendPort.html#call) method returns a [`Future`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Future.html) for the reply. If you don't bother of the reply and simply want to send a message, use [`send()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate/SendPort.html#send).

Have a look at [dart:isolate - Concurrency with Isolates](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-dartisolate---concurrency-with-isolates) for more informations.

For 3) it's explained in the above link :

> In the standalone VM, the `main()` function runs in the first isolate (also known as the *root isolate*). When the root isolate terminates, it terminates the whole VM, regardless of whether other isolates are still running. For more information, see [the section called “Keeping the root isolate alive”](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-keeping-the-root-isolate-alive).